# Do I need to buy CALs in case of FBA?

Tags: 2013, licensing

Do I need to buy user CALs when Form-base authentication is used in the intranet portal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you do,

https://products.office.com/en-us/sharepoint/sharepoint-licensing-overview

Reading a bit into the language here, they only care about actual number of users, not so much means of access.